# How to debug the error: java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am writing an app which is meant to help general doctors in treating elderly people. The goal is to avoid polypharmacy and it is based on the ATC (Anatomical Therapeutical Chemical) classification. I wrote a method that ads active substance to the DB and it works (I checked it on the h2 db) but I cannot write a proper test.

How can I investigate this problem?

Here is my test class:

```
package com.example.geriafarm.controllers;


import com.example.geriafarm.DTO.ATCdto;
import com.example.geriafarm.DTO.ActiveSubstDTO;
import com.example.geriafarm.entities.ATC;
import com.example.geriafarm.entities.ActiveSubst;
import com.example.geriafarm.repositories.ActiveSubstRepository;
import com.example.geriafarm.services.ATCService;
import com.example.geriafarm.services.ActiveSubstService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.UUID;

import static java.lang.String.format;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ActiveSubstControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ActiveSubstService activeSubstService;

    @Autowired
    ActiveSubstRepository activeSubstRepository;


    @Test
    @Transactional
    void shouldAddActiveSubstance() throws Exception {
        final UUID id = new UUID(1234,567);
        final String testName = "furosemid";
        final String atcDTOTest = "C03CA01";
        final ATC testATC = new ATC(null, "C","03","C","A","01");
        final ActiveSubst activeSubstTest = new ActiveSubst(id,testName, testATC);

        when(activeSubstService.addSubstance(any(ActiveSubstDTO.class))).thenReturn(activeSubstTest.getId());

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/activesubstances")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(format("{\"name\":\"%s\",\"atc\":\"%s\"}",  testName, atcDTOTest)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(testName)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.atc", is(atcDTOTest)));

    }
}
```

This is the ActiveSubstanceService class:

```
package com.example.geriafarm.services.implementation;

import com.example.geriafarm.DTO.ATCdto;
import com.example.geriafarm.DTO.ActiveSubstDTO;
import com.example.geriafarm.entities.ATC;
import com.example.geriafarm.entities.ActiveSubst;
import com.example.geriafarm.repositories.ATCRepository;
import com.example.geriafarm.repositories.ActiveSubstRepository;
import com.example.geriafarm.services.ActiveSubstService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class DefaultActiveSubstService implements ActiveSubstService {

    private final ActiveSubstRepository activeSubstRepository;
    private final ATCRepository atcRepository;

    public DefaultActiveSubstService(ActiveSubstRepository activeSubstRepository, ATCRepository atcRepository) {
        this.activeSubstRepository = activeSubstRepository;
        this.atcRepository = atcRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ActiveSubstDTO> getSubstances() {
        return null;
    }

    public static ATC createATCEntity(ATCdto atcDto) { //metoda przepisuje dane z frontendu(ATCdto) do poszczególnych pól w bazie danych
        ATC atcEntity = new ATC();
        atcEntity.setAnatomicalGr(atcDto.getAtcDto().substring(0, 1));
        atcEntity.setTherapeutSubgr(atcDto.getAtcDto().substring(1, 3));
        atcEntity.setPharmacolSubgr(atcDto.getAtcDto().substring(3, 4));
        atcEntity.setChemicalSubgr(atcDto.getAtcDto().substring(4, 5));
        atcEntity.setChemicalSubst(atcDto.getAtcDto().substring(5));
        return atcEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID addSubstance(ActiveSubstDTO activeSubstDTO) {


        final ActiveSubst activeSubst = activeSubstRepository.saveAndFlush(new ActiveSubst(null, activeSubstDTO.getName(), createATCEntity(activeSubstDTO.getAtc())
                )

        );

        return activeSubst.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ActiveSubstDTO> getSubstanceById(String id) {
        return activeSubstRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).map(ActiveSubstDTO::fromActiveSubstEnt);

    }

    @Override
    public ActiveSubstDTO updateSubstance(String id, ActiveSubstDTO activeSubstDTO) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ActiveSubstDTO> getSubstancesByMedicine(UUID medicineId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ActiveSubstDTO> getSubstancesByAnatomicalGroup(ATCdto atcDto) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ActiveSubstDTO> getSubstancesByTherapeuticSubgroup(ATCdto atcDto) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally the controller:

```
package com.example.geriafarm.controllers;

import com.example.geriafarm.DTO.ActiveSubstDTO;
import com.example.geriafarm.exceptions.GeriaException;
import com.example.geriafarm.services.ActiveSubstService;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/activesubstances")
public class ActiveSubstController {

    private final ActiveSubstService activeSubstService;

    public ActiveSubstController(ActiveSubstService activeSubstService) {
        this.activeSubstService = activeSubstService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addActiveSubst (@RequestBody ActiveSubstDTO activeSubstDTO) throws GeriaException, URISyntaxException {
        UUID activeSubstId = activeSubstService.addSubstance(activeSubstDTO);

        return ResponseEntity
                .created(new URI("/activesubstances/" + activeSubstId))
                .build();
    }


}
```

Edit: And here's the stack of error that I get:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /activesubstances
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"36"]
             Body = {"name":"furosemid","atc":"C03CA01"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstController
           Method = com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstController#addActiveSubst(ActiveSubstDTO)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"/activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /activesubstances
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"36"]
             Body = {"name":"furosemid","atc":"C03CA01"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstController
           Method = com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstController#addActiveSubst(ActiveSubstDTO)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"/activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237
          Cookies = []
2021-06-30 17:45:11.429  INFO 20568 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@43aaf813 testClass = ActiveSubstControllerTest, testInstance = com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstControllerTest@7d28efd5, testMethod = shouldAddActiveSubstance@ActiveSubstControllerTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name", mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@57ac5227 testClass = ActiveSubstControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.geriafarm.GeriafarmApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@4ba302e0 key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@23202fce, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6f1c29b7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@763dd5d5, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2b72cb8a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@5d99c6b5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4b3fa0b3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@52e7a6b2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@133e16fd], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name"

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:304)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.example.geriafarm.controllers.ActiveSubstControllerTest.shouldAddActiveSubstance(ActiveSubstControllerTest.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:386)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:342)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:301)
    ... 69 more
```

I'm new to Java and coding in general.

Comment: This is awfully complex code for someone new to coding and Java. Spring MVC + mocking + hibernate + JSON parsing is a lot to take on at the same time as learning Java.

Comment: Oh, it was an extremely intensive year of learning. That's probably my mistake: trying to get to know everything at the same time. I get a bit lost :/

Comment: Actually a very good question for a SO newbie, respect. It's clear what happens and why it's failing. I've posted an answer. Keep on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put the stack of error in your question?

Maybe your json from return of body of request, hasn`t a property with "name".

with your stack your body from return is empty.

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Location:"/activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /activesubstances/00000000-0000-04d2-0000-000000000237
          Cookies = []
```

you can remove the test of content like:

```java
mockMvc.perform(
                post("/activesubstances")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(format("{\"name\":\"%s\",\"atc\":\"%s\"}",  testName, atcDTOTest)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
```

or you can put the responseEntity from controller to return a DTO object with informations, and check it.

Comment: Thank you, Lucas. I've put the error stack.

Comment: The test passes when I put it like this :) Thank you for your help, it made many things clear to me

Comment: you're welcome, could you mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Well, after looking at your code, your `POST` method does not return a JSON payload with `name` and `atc` as part of it.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> addActiveSubst (@RequestBody ActiveSubstDTO activeSubstDTO) throws GeriaException, URISyntaxException {
    UUID activeSubstId = activeSubstService.addSubstance(activeSubstDTO);

    return ResponseEntity
                .created(new URI("/activesubstances/" + activeSubstId))
                .build();  // <-- you are returning an UUID only.
}
```

In your tests, you are asserting that you expect `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(testName)))` and `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.atc", is(atcDTOTest)))` in the **Response**, which does not match with your **Controller**.

You could give it a shot with this instead. In the end, your assertion must match the output of your Controller method.

```
mockMvc.perform(
                post("/activesubstances")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(format("{\"name\":\"%s\",\"atc\":\"%s\"}",  testName, atcDTOTest)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

**Edit:** Added one last comment on this answer, and changed to reflect the last proposal.

Comment: @nev3more, thank you for your idea. Unfortunately it didn't work. The springs MVC is really confusing for me. I'getting lost in it. I've go a lot of study ahead.

Comment: Ok, that answers it then. Simply remove the `.andExpect(jsonPath( ...` lines from your test. Your service is not returning any JSON payload with those fields present. Thus, you must not be asserting for those. Just keep this one `.andExpect(status().isCreated())`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you're returning an empty body (`ResponseEntity<Void>`) with a `Location` header:

```
        return ResponseEntity
                .created(new URI("/activesubstances/" + activeSubstId))
                .build();
```

And in the test, you're expecting a JSON with `name` and `atc` fields in it:

```
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(testName)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.atc", is(atcDTOTest)));
```

Therefore, the test is correctly failing.

What you have to fix is:

- If your want to return an empty body, remove the aforementioned lines from the test. You may just check the `Location` header instead.
- If your want to return the JSON in the response body (I guess you expected it to be `ActiveSubstDTO`?), you have to return the appropriate `ResponseEntity<YourResponseType>` instead (e.g. `ResponseEntity<ActiveSubstDTO>`).